# How can I make the entries in my bibliography appear with their entire first name?

Tags: back-referencing

I realize that the answer to this question MUST be somewhere already, but after over an hour of google I just don't know what else to do then to ping you, hat-in-hand.

I'm using natbib and \bibliographystyle{apalike} and want my references to appear not as "Smith, J. (2019)". But as "Smith, John (2019)".

How do I do this? My excuses for the ignorant question!!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275409/134144 might be helpful.

Comment: I wasn't brave enough to edit the bot file but it turns out that it's a piece of cake. thanks for pointing me there!